# java fx localToScene() Coords

Tags: javafx-8

We have a java fx 8 application which progressively creates Panes at runtime based on received environment events. As they are created, these Panes are then added as children of other Panes which all form part of the entire Scene. All this works great and, when shown on the screen, all Panes are created and can be seen appearing on the screen as the events come in and their positions can be seen to be adjusting as other Panes are created and added around them, etc.

A problem however arises when, given other external environment events we want to then display a message transitioning between two of the created Panes (Panes which were created at runtime). To do this, we get the centre X,Y coords of each of the two Panes by using the following snippet of sample code:

```
Bounds localBounds1 = pane1.getBoundsInLocal();
Point2D localPoint1 = new Point2D(localBounds1.getWidth()/2, 
localBounds1.getHeight()/2);
Point2D scenePoint1 = pane1.localToScene(localPoint1);

Bounds localBounds2 = pane2.getBoundsInLocal();
Point2D localPoint2 = new Point2D(localBounds2.getWidth()/2, 
localBounds2.getHeight()/2);
Point2D scenePoint2 = pane2.localToScene(localPoint2);

// here after we create a PathTransition from scenePoint1 to scenePoint2 and play it to see a message move from one Pane to the other.
```

The problem we have is that almost all of the time, the `Point2D` coords returned by the call to a pane's `.localToScene()` are not necessarily the coords currently displayed on the screen. It is as though the coords returned are the initial coords of the Panes when they were first added in but, before other Panes where created and added around them (thus adjusting the Pane's Scene coordinates).

We have tried forcing calls to `.requestLayout()` and `.layout()` before calculating `scenePoint1` and `scenePoint2` but the coords returned are almost always old and obsolete.

Is there anything that we are not doing right in order to get the current x,y coords of a Node relative to the Scene?

Comment: It might be tricky, but is it possible to create a [MCVE] for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not at all to do with anything java fx related.

It was a coding mistake in our part were we were getting the Panes from a custom made Map which was not being managed properly.